# Flexbox table with fixed column and header

Tags: html, css, html-table

**Info**

Hello i have a flexbox table that I simplified into code snippet bellow. I have table data in this format

```
tableData = [
  {
    category: "category name",
    rows: [
      {
        rowName: "row name",
        columns: [
          { columnName: "column name" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and the table work so far. But with more data the table is useless because I cant see first column that contains important info for other columns. Another important thing is that `<div class="table-section">` should serve as "window" to look at the table, because I don't want to scroll whole page.

**Question**

How can I fix first column in position and scroll rest of the table horizontaly and verticaly? Should I use basic html table or different approach? Thanks

```css
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.container {
    padding: 20px 35px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.info-section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex: none;
}
.table-section {
    border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.table-container {
    width: max-content !important;
    padding: 5px;
}
.table-category {
    margin: 15px;
    margin: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.table-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.table-column {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
    display: flex;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="info-section">
      <h1>Info etc.</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tempor auctor tempor. Sed blandit et tortor varius porta. Sed sed pharetra ex. Nam ultrices elit velit, ac ultricies quam malesuada non. Nunc suscipit nibh dictum felis dignissim, quis ultrices lacus vulputate. In ligula ante, bibendum accumsan aliquam sagittis, iaculis id lorem. Suspendisse volutpat mollis tempor. Duis et nisl sit amet erat viverra ornare sit amet porta mauris.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="table-section">
      <div class="table-container">
        <div class="table-category">
          <div class="table-row">
            <div class="table-column">
              fixed column
            </div>
            <div class="table-column">
              Fixed Heading
            </div>
            <div class="table-column">
              Fixed Heading
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="table-row">
            <div class="table-column">
              fixed column
            </div>
            <div class="table-column">
              data 1
            </div>
            <div class="table-column">
              data 2
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="table-row">
            <div class="table-column">
              fixed column
            </div>
            <div class="table-column">
              data 1
            </div>
            <div class="table-column">
              data 2
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-category">
          <div class="table-row">
            <div class="table-column">
              fixed column
            </div>
            <div class="table-column">
              data 1
            </div>
            <div class="table-column">
              data 2
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="table-row">
            <div class="table-column">
              fixed column
            </div>
            <div class="table-column">
              data 1
            </div>
            <div class="table-column">
              data 2
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="table-row">
            <div class="table-column">
              fixed column
            </div>
            <div class="table-column">
              data 1
            </div>
            <div class="table-column">
              data 2
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="table-row">
            <div class="table-column">
              fixed column
            </div>
            <div class="table-column">
              data 1
            </div>
            <div class="table-column">
              data 2
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="table-row">
            <div class="table-column">
              fixed column
            </div>
            <div class="table-column">
              data 1
            </div>
            <div class="table-column">
              data 2
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="table-row">
            <div class="table-column">
              fixed column
            </div>
            <div class="table-column">
              data 1
            </div>
            <div class="table-column">
              data 2
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="table-row">
            <div class="table-column">
              fixed column
            </div>
            <div class="table-column">
              data 1
            </div>
            <div class="table-column">
              data 2
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="table-row">
            <div class="table-column">
              fixed column
            </div>
            <div class="table-column">
              data 1
            </div>
            <div class="table-column">
              data 2
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```